# is there any visio parser that support VSDX extention for java?

Tags: java, parsing, apache-poi, visio

I tried the POI Lib to parse vsd and it is working well
but when i tried to parse VSDX I got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.hdgf.extractor.VisioTextExtractor.<init>(VisioTextExtractor.java:65)
at VSDDumper.main(VSDDumper.java:19)
```

is there any visio parser that support VSDX extention??

Comment: Which version of poi are you using? As the error suggests, POI does support the format, you are just not using the correct classes.

Comment: the latest (poi-3.10-FINAL)